# inserting mulitiple RDDs / dataframes to a global view

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am using spark streaming to receive call records from kakfa broker every 10 minutes. I want to insert these records into some temptable (global?) and keep inserting as soon as I receive from Kakfa.

Please note that **I do not want to store in hive**. After every insert I want to check if calls by a particular number exceeded 20 (for example). Below is the code which I have written which converts every `rdd` to `df` and then create a temp view. However, I guess that view will contain only last `RDD`. How to keep inserting records in same view  and run sql later?

```
val topics = Array("AIRDRMAIN", "")
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
      streamingContext,
      PreferConsistent,
      Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
    )
val Lines = messages.map(line => line.value())
val AirDRStream = Lines.map(AirDRFilter.parseAirDR)
AirDRStream.foreachRDD(foreachFunc = rdd => {
  System.out.println("--- New RDD with " + rdd.count() + " records");
  if (rdd.count() == 0) {
     println("---WANG No logs received in this time interval=================")
  } else {
     val sqlContext = SparkSession
       .builder()
       .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
       .getOrCreate()
   import sqlContext.implicits._
   rdd.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("AIR")
   val FilteredDR = sqlContext.sql("select refillProfileID, count(*) from AIR group by refillProfileID")
   FilteredDR.show()
   }
  })
  streamingContext.start()
  streamingContext.awaitTermination()
```

Below is updated code after adding globalTempView logic.

```
val schema_string = "subscriberNumber, originNodeType, originHostName, originOperatorID, originTimeStamp, currentServiceClass, voucherBasedRefill, transactionAmount, refillProfileID, voucherGroupID, externalData1, externalData2"
val schema_rdd = StructType(schema_string.split(",")
                 .map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))
val init_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], schema_rdd)

println("initial count of initial RDD is " + init_df.count())

init_df.createGlobalTempView("AIRGLOBAL")

AirDRStream.foreachRDD(foreachFunc = rdd => {
  System.out.println("--- New RDD with " + rdd.count() + " records");
  if (rdd.count() == 0) {
    println("--- No logs received in this time interval=================")
  } else {
    init_df.union(rdd.toDF())
    println("after union count of initial  RDD is " + init_df.count())
    rdd.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("AIR")
    val FilteredDR = sqlContext.sql("select  count(*) from AIR ")
    val globalviewinsert = sqlContext.sql("Insert into global_temp.AIRGLOBAL select * from AIR ")
    val globalview = sqlContext.sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  global_temp.AIRGLOBAL ")
    FilteredDR.show()
    globalviewinsert.show()
    globalview.show()
  }
})
streamingContext.start()
streamingContext.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a  Global Temporary View. Quoting from documentation

> Temporary views in Spark SQL are session-scoped and will disappear if
>   the session that creates it terminates. If you want to have a
>   temporary view that is shared among all sessions and keep alive until
>   the Spark application terminates, you can create a global temporary
>   view. Global temporary view is tied to a system preserved database
>   global_temp, and we must use the qualified name to refer it, e.g.
>   SELECT * FROM global_temp.view1.

```
// Register the DataFrame as a global temporary view
df.createGlobalTempView("people")

// Global temporary view is tied to a system preserved database `global_temp`
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM global_temp.people").show()
// +----+-------+
// | age|   name|
// +----+-------+
// |null|Michael|
// |  30|   Andy|
// |  19| Justin|
// +----+-------+

// Global temporary view is cross-session
spark.newSession().sql("SELECT * FROM global_temp.people").show()
```

Comment: thanks. Any idea how to insert data into global temp view? I tried inserting from temp view created from RDD -> data frame but got assertion error java.lang.AssertionError

Comment: please paste the full stacktrace.

Comment: print the schemas of both the tables and also when you performa transformation on th dataset/dataframe always assign it to a new variable and perform operations on it. DF/Datasets are immutable.

Comment: the schemas are identical.